# What are the invariant structures in special relativity?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, geometry, invariants

What geometric structures in Minkowski spacetime are Lorentz invariant?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, as such, _all_ geometric structures are, by definition, invariant under coordinate transformations because geometric structures are physical entities that live on their own without needing a coordinate system. For example, the momentum of a particle is a vector given by $\vec{\mathcal{P}} = p^\mu \vec{e}_\mu$ which is a Lorentz invariant. We usually say that momentum transforms under a Lorentz transformation because its components $p^\mu$ do that. See, the books by Taylor and Wheeler or the introductory chapter of MTW for a more eloquent elaboration.

Comment: If you are not considering the Lorentz group's double cover, it is known that all invariant tensors are combinations of the Levi Civita symbol and Minkowski metric.

Answer (score 2):

You have to say what you mean by geometric structures, and also by Lorentz transformations.

I will assume what you mean by geometric structures are sets of Minkowski spacetime, and that by Lorentz invariant you mean invariant under proper ortochronous Lorentz transformations (the ones that do not invers the space and time directions).

Under that condition, the only sets that are Lorentz invariant are the sets that can be written as

$$H_f = \{x^\mu\in \mathbb{M}_4\,:\, f( x^\mu x_\mu) = \text{const.}\},$$

where $f$ is any scalar function. The reason for this is that the only trully invariant object in special relativity is the Minkowski metric $\eta$, which can only produce scalars from a point (vector) $x^\mu$ by the contraction $\eta_{\mu\nu}x^\mu x^\nu$.

Examples of sets defined by expressions as the one above are, for instance, the light cone $x^\mu x_\mu = 0$ and the on shell mass hyperbolas $x^\mu x_\mu = \pm m^2$.

Comment: What does "cte." stand for here?

Comment: cte stands for constant